# Can I convert my 529 college savings plan to a Coverdell ESA?

Tags: united-states, education-savings, 529-plan, coverdell-esa

Can I convert my 529 college savings plan to a Coverdell ESA, or am I stuck with my 529 plan?

Comment: Coverdells are fading out.  You might know this, but just in case somebody else reads this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can roll a Coverdell ESA into a 529, but you cannot go the other way around.

529's have contribution limits an order of magnitude higher than that of a Coverdell ESA. If you could roll a 529 into a Coverdell, it would defeat the purpose of the limit on the ESA.